# Проблема при работе с gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Вижу, что на форуме неоднократно обсуждалась тема работы получения данных  из json с помощью  библиотеки gson , но решил спросить  ещё раз.

Имеется json-структура следующего вида:

```
{
    "collection_rest_access":
 {
    "@COUNT":"1",
    "@START":"1",
    "@TOTAL_COUNT":"1",
    "rest_access":
  {
    "@id":"400001",
    "@REL_ATTR":"400001",
    "@COMMON_NAME":"538213764",
    "expiration_date":1430128973
  }
 }
}
```

Мне необходимо получить значение переменной expiration_date.

Создал  следующие классы для получения данных:

```
public class CollectionAccess {
ArrayList<RestAccess> restaccess;

public void setAccess (ArrayList<RestAccess> rr) {
    restaccess = rr;
}


public ArrayList<RestAccess> getAccess () {
    return restaccess;
}

}

public class RestAccess {
String expiration_date;


public void setExpDate (String expdate){
    this.expiration_date = expdate;
}


public String getExpDate() {
    return this.expiration_date;
};
}
```

Вот вызов классов из  программы:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String fpath = "C:\\BPMINST\\json.txt";

    String json_str = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        json_str = json_str + sCurrentLine;
    }
    System.out.println(json_str);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    CollectionAccess orderHeader = gson.fromJson(json_str, CollectionAccess.class);
    if (orderHeader==null){
        System.out.println("orderHeader is null");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("orderHeader not  is null");
    };
    ArrayList<RestAccess> orderDetailList = orderHeader.getAccess();
    if (orderDetailList!=null){
         System.out.println(orderDetailList.size());
    };
}
```

но результат отработки возвращает null. Подскажите пожалуйста, что  может быть не так с классами?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, скорее всего, возникает из-за того, что типы данных совершенно не соответствуют тому, что содержится в JSON. Поле в первом объекте называется `collection_rest_access`, а в коде оно названо `restaccess`. Тип для него тоже задан неверно, в поле хранится объект, а тип поля в коде - почему-то коллекция.

Кроме того, я бы не стал использовать GSON в случаях, когда нужно достать одно поле, проще воспользоваться [библиотекой JSON-Java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java).

Comment: Не "скорее всего" а именно поэтому. Если пользоваться GSON о нужно создать 3 вложенных друг в друга класса: основной, второй который получается из `collection_rest_access`, и третий, который получается из второго по `rest_access`

Comment: Ну и как же ТС сможет воспользоваться библиотекой JSON-Java? Почитает исходники и поймет в каком случае что надо вызывать?

Comment: @avp Не понял комментарий, если честно. Просто предлагаю воспользоваться другой библиотекой, которая, как мне кажется, больше подходит к данному случаю, потому что с ней даже не придётся создавать никакие классы. При чём тут её исходники?

Comment: А Вы по своей ссылке тексты-то почитали? Там же совершенно нет ни инструкций, как обычный человек может либой воспользоваться, ни даже примеров. Конечно, все мы знаем, что 90% githab это просто большая помойка, так тем более надо как-то аккуратней давать советы.

Comment: @avp Это не просто какая-то левая библиотека, это [официальная библиотека, которой предлагается работать с JSON](http://www.json.org/java/). И найти примеры, как с ней работать, вряд ли представляет проблему.

Comment: Короче, Вы сами ей не пользовались. Между прочим, на json.org тоже ни за что не отвечают (это я по сишным либам хорошо знаю).

Comment: @avp Если б не пользовался, то не писал бы. Я так и не понял, из-за чего этот сыр-бор. Я посоветовал инструмент, который, на мой взгляд, подходит в этом случае. Документация есть, куча людей используют. Лицензия такая же, как и у всех бесплатных проектов. Если спрашивающему не понравится, пусть не пользуется. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Ну и где там документация? Я вот решил ознакомиться, но не нашел.

Comment: Ответил [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23086/discussion-between-malcolm-and-avp), обсуждение уже явно вышло за рамки комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно  ли я понимаю, что  в дополнении к ранее созданным классам CollectionAccess  и RestAccess  мне нужно  создать  ещё класс AccessClass вот такого вида:

```
   public class AccessClass {
    CollectionAccess  collection_rest_access;


    public void setCollectionAccess( CollectionAccess  acc){
        this.collection_rest_access = acc;
    };


    public CollectionAccess getCollectionAccess() {
        return this.collection_rest_access;
    }


}
```

и ,соответственно, мне необходимо в коде использовать именно класс AccessClass ?

Comment: Не надо оставлять обновления к вопросу в ответах, воспользуйся комментариями или отредактируй вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, учту.

Comment: Для данного примера заставил  код работать. Но возник следующий вопрос: если мне заранее не известно вернет ли мне json список значений или же 1 значение: то  есть  я имею ввиду, что  объект rest_access может быть либо списком значений, либо  вернуть 1. Как мне следует в этом случае изменить код класса AccessClass?

Comment: Если это может быть то один объект, то массив, я бы вообще не стал использовать Gson в таком случае, он предполагает, что JSON всегда имеет одну и ту же структуру, и использовал бы JSON-Java. Вообще, это уже отдельный вопрос, так что лучше его и задать отдельно.

Comment: @Malcolm: вся информация, которая необходима для ответа, должна быть в вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Comment: @jfs Если это информация, которая нужна для ответа, то да, а если это вопрос про сам ответ, то это уже больше подходит для комментария.

Comment: @Malcolm: я не вижу здесь ответа. Содержимое очевидно является вопросом. Автор просто не ту форму отправил. Формат сайта в отличии от других форумов: один вопрос -- несколько ответов на странице.

Comment: @jfs Верно, я именно это и говорю.